# How to run each integration test truly individually in Spring, or at the very least run all commandlinerunners before each test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm using spring-boot-starter-test.

I have a bunch of integration tests that insert data into the application using REST calls. I run these with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

After each test I end up with some data in my database. I want each test to be truly self-contained, but I haven't found a way of doing this. I tried putting @Rollback on each test, but since I am inserting data externally by REST calls this understandably doesn't work.

So previously I resorted to deleting all data between tests, in a rather low-level way, just by executing a delete query (i.e. something like `Query deleteProjects = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Project"); deleteProjects.executeUpdate();`) for each entity after running a test.

However, I recently added an admin user account that will be created in a CommandLineRunner. I found out this CommandLineRunner is also only ran once for all tests combined, so after the first test finishes and all data is deleted, I lose my admin role.

What would be a good way to set this up? I realize starting the whole application takes some time so a complete new startup wouldn't be ideal. Some way to tell Spring to run the CommandLineRunner before each test would be good. I don't want to instantiate and run it myself, that would be quite hacky and I'm not sure how that would work in terms of transactions. I could exclude this admin user account from being deleted in the query but then I'm still hacking around the system.

Comment: Why not inserting the role data after each executed test ? In this way you ensure that the role is always present in the DB.

Comment: I cannot insert the administrator account through a REST call, because there is no way to create an administrator account without already having an administrator account.

Comment: So why do you delete this information if you don't have other way to add it then ?

Comment: Because I want a clean slate between every test, so I delete ALL data in between. Yes I could create an exception in the where clause in the delete query, but I'd much rather have a way to tell Spring to run the CommandLineRunner before each test, or even for Spring to do the whole cleanup for me. I firmly believe tests should be self-contained anyway. There shouldn't be a difference between running 1 test and running all of them together.

Comment: From the time where you don't clear the whole spring context and that you increase the number of tests, you will necessary increase the odds to have side effects between the tests. Today you have this issue but you could have news in the time. It makes the test architecture complex and error prone I found. If I were you I would choose one of these two options : accept that integration tests be coupled between or accept the time of a restart  between tests I don't want to couple (integration tools serve this purpose and should not be annoyed to pass for example from 3 minutes to 6 minutes).

Comment: Is there an easy way to configure a restart between each test? I wouldn't mind so much, especially for the tests that run on the build environment.

Comment: The simplest way is writing a test by @SpringBootTest  test class. It is rather cumbersome I know.

Comment: Edited my post to add this, I am already using @SpringBootTest. But that still only runs the application once and then fires off all individual tests.

Comment: Would something like DBUnit do what you're wanting?

Comment: @chrylis that looks like an interesting library but it seems to be mostly for helping to setup some data or verifying database contents. I do not want to go outside my own regular code for setting up an admin account, I feel it wouldn’t be an adequate test.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have a chicken and egg problem with needing to have this admin account existing and the Spring context existing for this admin account. What I find a good way to do this is to have a Spring Profile `@Profile("test")` and put this on some `Component` which creates this admin account you need:

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class CreateAdminBean {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo repo;

    public CreateAdminBean() {
        // TODO your job but something like:
        User admin = new User();
        admin.setAdmin(true);
        repo.create(admin);
    }
}
```

If you want your tests to be truly independent of each-other you will need to recreate the context every time and insure your database is wiped each time. This will cost you allot of time and IMO is unnecessary but if you have your reasons you have your reasons. I personally would mock all the services.

You can just have your database JPA Hibernate you would have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop`. I typically don't do this and just have a method which clears all tables and have that run after each test, but that's not what you are asking in your question, and I would expect to see a `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` in your test code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Well it isn't strictly necessary to wipe everything, I would just prefer that so it's easier to isolate each case, especially when it comes to security testing.